# KeyListener not instantiated in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I'm creating a simple little game and I'd like some help to find what error I'm making. The idea is to have some panels stored in a CardLayout inside the main frame and switch between them when necessary; I've created a custom JFrame (MainFrame) and a bunch of custom JPanels, one of them is the GamePanel which it has attached to a custom KeyListener (MovementListener) to capture the key event and move the player as necessary. The problem is that when I'm switching to GamePanel it seems like the keyListener is not instantiate.
To be clear, doing a bunch of test, it's resulted that in the addKeyListener() method, the "new MovementListener()" part is null, but I can't figure it out why.

Here it is the MovementListener class:

```
package controller.listeners;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import application.core.GameController;
import entities.Player;
import movement.Direction;

public class MovementListener implements KeyListener {

    private Player player;

    public MovementListener() {
        this.player=GameController.getInstance().getPlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_W:
            player.move(Direction.NORTH);
            player.getAnimatedSprite().startMoving();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_A:
            player.move(Direction.WEST);
            player.getAnimatedSprite().startMoving();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_S:
            player.move(Direction.SOUTH);
            player.getAnimatedSprite().startMoving();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_D:
            player.move(Direction.EAST);
            player.getAnimatedSprite().startMoving();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_W:
            player.getAnimatedSprite().stopMoving();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_A:
            player.getAnimatedSprite().stopMoving();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_S:
            player.getAnimatedSprite().stopMoving();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_D:
            player.getAnimatedSprite().stopMoving();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

}
```

GamePanel class:

```
package graphics.panels;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import application.core.GameController;
import controller.listeners.MovementListener;
import entities.Entity;
import entities.Living;
import graphics.ConstantsCollector;
import graphics.sprites.AnimatedSprite;
import graphics.sprites.Tile;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

    public static final String NAME="Game";

    private static GamePanel instance=null;

    private Tile grassTile;
    private Entity[][] logicMap;

    private GamePanel() {
        super();

        logicMap = GameController.getInstance().logicMap;
        grassTile = new Tile(ConstantsCollector.GRASSTEXTURE);
        addKeyListener(new MovementListener());

        setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        setVisible(true);
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocusInWindow();
        grabFocus();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        drawFloorMap(g);
        drawObjects(g);
        drawEntities(g);
    }

    private void drawFloorMap(Graphics g) {
        for(int i = 0; i < ConstantsCollector.MAP_SIZE; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < ConstantsCollector.MAP_SIZE; j++)
                g.drawImage(grassTile.getSprite(), Tile.calculateXPosition(i), Tile.calculateYPosition(j), Tile.calculateWidth(), Tile.calculateHeight(), null);
    }

    private void drawObjects(Graphics g) {
        for(int i = 0; i < ConstantsCollector.MAP_SIZE; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < ConstantsCollector.MAP_SIZE; j++)
                if (logicMap[i][j]!=null && !(logicMap[i][j] instanceof Living))
                    g.drawImage(logicMap[i][j].getTile().getSprite(), logicMap[i][j].getTile().getWidth(), logicMap[i][j].getTile().getHeight(), null);
                else
                    g.drawImage(grassTile.getSprite(), Tile.calculateXPosition(i), Tile.calculateYPosition(j), Tile.calculateWidth(), Tile.calculateHeight(), null);
    }

    private void drawEntities(Graphics g)   {
        for(int i = 0; i < ConstantsCollector.MAP_SIZE; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < ConstantsCollector.MAP_SIZE; j++)
                if (logicMap[i][j]!=null && (logicMap[i][j] instanceof Living))
                {
                    AnimatedSprite sprite=((Living)logicMap[i][j]).getAnimatedSprite();
                    g.drawImage(sprite.getCurrentImage(), sprite.getWidht(), sprite.getHeight(), null);
                }
    }

    public void update() {
        repaint();
    }

    public static GamePanel getInstance() {
        if (instance==null)
            instance=new GamePanel();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: *The problem is that when I'm switching to GamePanel it seems like the keyListener is not instantiate* - KeyEvents are only dispatched to the component with focus. Don't use a KeyListener. Instead you should be using Key Bindings. See [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more information and working examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KeyListener will not work on JPanel, use registerKeyboardAction method. I'd better do smth like this

```
class Movement {
    Player player;

    public void move(Direction direction) {
        player.move(direction);
        player.getAnimatedSprite().startMoving();
    }
}

class GamePanel extends JPanel {
    Movement movement = new Movement();
    private GamePanel() {
        KeyStroke keystroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, false); 
        registerKeyboardAction(movementListener(Direction.NORTH), keystroke, JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        // register other key strokes
    }
    ActionListener movementListener(final Direction direction) {
        return new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                movement.move(direction);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ActionListener can be simplified to lambda in java8

Comment: The API for the `registerKeyboardAction(...)` method states: *This method is now obsolete, please use a combination of getActionMap() and getInputMap() for similar behavior.*

Comment: Entire Swing is obsolete:)